# How do I create a persistent queue for a large number of files?

Tags: amazon-ec2, queue, bigdata, amazon-sqs, apache-kafka

Currently I am implementing a big data solution using ec2 + sqs + s3. The idea is that I have an enormous database of files being hosted on s3. Clients using my application would submit a rule match, that would attempt to match all relevant files available on s3, and then evaluate a conditional statement, returning output to the user showing which files matched the conditional.

I obviously cannot perform my rule match over my s3 files directly, as then there is no preventing duplicate jobs across the ec2 instances I would spin up to do the rule matches. There would also be no division of labor.

My initial solution was to incorporate Amazon SQS: when a client made a request, all files in S3 would be loaded into the queue. This would allow my ec2 instances to perform division of labor + no duplicates, as SQS takes care of this.

However, using the above solution, I would be loading all my files into the SQS queue every time a client request is made, which is clearly wasteful (not to mention the skyrocketing SQS cost). Ideally I would want to have a persistent queue that loads all my files once (and additionally loads more when more files are added to my s3).

Any ideas about how to create a big data queue structure?? Should I ditch SQS, or should I adapt SQS to operate like a persistent queue by not deleting messages after they are processed and keeping a reserved SQS instance always running?

Thanks.

Comment: Requests for off-site resources ("What is a big data service for...?") are off-topic.  Your question might be better received if you simply ask how to do what you want to do (and be more specific about what that is, if possible), rather than asking for a service.

Comment: As a note, SQS does _not_ guarantee no duplicates - it has _at least once_ delivery. You will need to handle duplicate deliveries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your rule matching thing is based on file metadata rather than file contents, you can store metadata about your files in an actual database, like Amazon DynamoDB, and do your matching like that.

Storing your data "permanently" in SQS (not deleting messages) is not a great idea - messages have a limited size, and if you don't delete messages, they become available again for subsequent requests - you're going to get a lot more duplication this way.  Also, SQS does *not* provide any guarantees around duplication - it's in fact a "at least once" delivery.

If you are running your rule matching on file contents (possibly in addition to metadata), which is what it sounds like you really want, then you can use [Amazon SimpleWorkflow](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-intro-to-swf.html)  and the [Flow API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/awsflow-basics-application-structure.html) built on top of it:

SWF have two main components - the workflow (which maintains the state) and the activities (stateless code that performs the work). For your case, the workflow would divide each request into many chunks of work and submit activities to the SWF service. Your activity workers would run on many EC2 instances - their job is to essentially pick up the job (ie: run your rule matching code on the assigned subset of S3 files) and return the result. The workflow would then consolidate the activity results and do something with the result.

The [Flow framework recipies](http://aws.amazon.com/code/2535278400103493) document has some good examples of the code patterns you'll need to execute many activities concurrently and consolidate the results.

**So, in summary, to specifically answer your question: ditch SQS and use SWF which is designed for this sort of usage pattern.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't even consider AWF. I ended up using Celery + RabbitMQ, a distributed queue system.